# How to figure out the error when library ggplot2?

Tags: r, lazy-loading

```
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt) -- "Eye Holes"
Copyright (C) 2023 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

> library(ggplot2)
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'ggplot2':
 attachNamespace() when 'ggplot2' fails, the details:
  Call: runHook(".onLoad", env, package.lib, package)
  Error: lazy-load database 'C:/Users/15195/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/withr/R/withr.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning message:
In runHook(".onLoad", env, package.lib, package) :
  internal error -3 in R_decompress1
```

I tried to remove the previous `ggplot2` package and install again :

```
install.packages('ggplot2', dependencies = TRUE)
```

But error still happened.

I uninstalled R and R studio, but error happened again.

Comment: Looks like the problem is with `withr`, not `ggplot2`. Try restarting R then running `install.packages("withr")` then see if `library(withr)` works

Comment: Thank you so much! It is definitely problem with withr. I delected the withr manually and install again, it works.